# adding an event listener to input to make a calculation and return the answer

Tags: javascript, html, dom

so, i am supposed to make a function that calculates the fibonacci sequence,which i did.
later on i made a button with an id name, and input with an id name.
and now i needed to display the sequence's sum on the page, which i did.. (look at code below)
and now i need to make the button somehow to trigger the function and calculate the input number's sum which the user entered, on the screen.
can someone help me with the syntax?
i know that i need to add an event listener for the button, which i did.
later i need to link the function param into the input's variable that i have created.
but what next? and what is the correct syntax?
can someone point me to the right direction?
thanks!

what i have tried:

```
let paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraph");
let input = document.getElementById("calcInput").value;
let button = document.getElementById("calcButton");
button.addEventListener(getValue(calc));
function calc(x) {
    let a = 0;
    let b = 1;
    c = x;
    for (let i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c
    }
    paragraph.innerHTML = `<p>${c}</p>` ; 
}
calc(7);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use button.[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

For example

```js
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calc(7)
});
```